# DataTables Stisla Template

Tags: laravel, datatables

[image colvis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2geM.png)
I want to add a colvis button to my datatables but here I use the stisla template, how do I add the colvis and it works. I also have difficulty setting the style of the button, how do I set it using the Stisla template

here I added colvis but it doesn't work, it can't be pressed. and how do I set the width of the select page too because when I press 100, the 0 is not visible